# How to add an EventBridge rule to hit an API endpoint on a schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I have an existing rule in AWS EventBridge that simply hits an API endpoint every day. Since I created that rule, something seems to have changed, and I have no idea how to set up another rule that hits a different endpoint every hour.

I've created an 'API destination' in Eventbridge called 'process-hourly'.

And I've gone through the first screen of creating a rule, setting the CRON-based schedule to be 0 10 * * ? * (10am every day).

But the *next* screen is asking me to choose a target API (see attached screenshot), and I've no idea what I'm supposed to be choosing here.

The AWS docs seem to be out of date and don't feature this screen.

How do I add a rule that simply hits an API destination in Eventbridge?
[image: Eventbridge target type]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an EventBridge rule, don't click on `continue on event bridge scheduler` but click on the button bottom left: `continue to create rule`. That will continue to another page to setup the schedule and then you can chose your API.

I'll also suggest to create this via cdk or Cloudformation in order to reproduce it in more repeatable way. The UI might change while API call should remain. If you don't know how to setup this via cdk or CloudFormation, I very often use a tool named: [former2.com](https://former2.com/). It is a tool that can help you in defining Infrastructure as Code from existing aws resources. It can generate CloudFormation or cdk code. Very useful.

There is an AWS blog post that explains it: [Accelerate infrastructure as code development with open source Former2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/accelerate-infrastructure-as-code-development-with-open-source-former2/)

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. I've now just noticed the 'advert' at the bottom of the form that says "EventBridge Scheduler - A new AWS scheduling capability!". The Scheduler button is the clear call-to-action, so I didn't even notice the rule button alternative.